# IIS 301 Redirect - any way of informing the final site of the original URL

Tags: asp.net, http, redirect, request

Is there any way of doing a 301 redirect such that the final destination url can ascertain the *original* URL? E.g.

Request: www.somesite.com/Page1 -> 301 Redirect -> www.anothersite.com/SectionA/Page1

I'd like the tech at anothersite.com to be able to check the request and 'know' it was redirected here from somesite.com.

UPDATE:

e.g.

Site A => click anchor => Site B (which has moved) => 301 Redirect => Site C

I need, at Site C to know that the Request has been through the redirection process at Site B.

UPDATE 2:

I have no control over the technology that is doing the Redirecting.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is Request.UrlReferrer returning null?

Comment: No, but I think it holds the URL of Site A.

Comment: Might check this related one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208114/asp-net-detecting-if-referrer-was-from-a-301-permanent-redirect

Comment: Thanks for that link - doesn't look like its going to be possible esp. as I have no control over the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is stateless and because [the specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) doesn't create any specific mechanism to allow the redirectee to understand it has been redirected to you have to assume that clients will create a brand new request.

If you have no control over the redirection I feel this isn't possible.